# Simple, easy software for recording over yourself

Tags: software, recording

I've been looking for some programs that could layer audio files, so I could play a couple different voices on my guitar and put them together into one song. There isn't any other classical guitarists around my area (except my two professors) so if I want to make a duo, trio, quartet, I've got to do it myself. Mostly though, I just want to experiment.

So I look around for a program that could do that (first Windows Movie Maker. Didn't work at *all*). Nothing I found was free or simple.

Anybody know of a simple, free program like that? And for Windows.

Comment: I'm wondering what search terms you were using - this is a huge area, so there are a large number of free applications to do this sort of thing.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Software Recommendations.

Comment: "so if I want to make a duo, trio, quartet, I've got to do it myself." Well, it certainly worked well for Danny Elfman.

Comment: @fNek where would that be?

Comment: @Zack http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - but only a moderator can do that

Comment: Do you have access to an iPad? GarageBand is brilliant for this and very cheap, but it's Apple only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do free live software looping I would suggest the Mobius looper: http://www.circularlabs.com

If you want to layer audio files and loop them for free, I would suggest Audacity: http://audacity.sourceforge.net

For hardware and for paid software I would have other suggestions.